# unxpected token when hosting on codesandbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Im working on a project where im trying to host it on codesandbox yet falling. The project works on local computer without any issue but not on codesandbox.

Here is the error im getting

```js
Unexpected token (7:3)

   5 | 
   6 | const App = ({ children }) => (
>  7 |   <>
     |   ^
   8 |     <Header />
   9 | 
  10 |     <main>
```

Here is the link to [the project](https://codesandbox.io/s/2ok82jrpkn)

Here is the link to the main source code on [github](https://github.com/keithweaver/MERN-boilerplate)

Comment: OK, which file is it in the codesandbox?

Comment: you can find the file under /client/app/components/App/App.js

Comment: Seems like short syntax for the fragment is not supported in Codesandbox. https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client/issues/992
You can change `<>` to `React.Fragment` and it should work.

Comment: Since you're trying to use an old boilerplate, might I suggest moving away from it, and instead using one I actively maintain (and use).  I created a boilerplate that's somewhat like the CRA (in terms of functionality and ease of use), but: It's pre-configured for module imports from within JS/SCSS files (includes notes on how to do so), pre-commit hook for style and JS linting, pre-configured redux store, incorporates redux dev window tool, errors overlay, supports Fragment shorthand syntax, and much more. Give it a try: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Webpack-React-Boilerplate/tree/fullstack

Comment: i checked you boilerplate yet doesnt work on codesandbox